# Insert into array by spaces

Tags: php, arrays, text-files

I have this TXT file, which each line I would to insert into array, like this:

> Array ( [0] => [1] => 8100 [2] => 623 [3] => 09:04 [4] => AM [5] => 00:26 [6] => L [7] => S-ED [8] => 768 [9] => #4506856439 [10] => 00:01 [11] => )

```
 CO     USER    TIME    DURATION  TYPE   ACCOUNT_CODE  CALLED_NUM      RING_TIME
 8100   623   09:04 AM     00:26  L S-E               250821613987
 8021   8816  09:06 AM     00:20  I S-E  D 768        #4506856439        00:01
 8020         09:06 AM            I  N   D 603        #45424044499        00:30
 8011         09:07 AM     00:11  I S-E  D 727        #7546355292        00:02
  "     8817               00:11  
  "                        00:02  H  
 8100   623   09:07 AM     00:01  L S-E               5542204034
 8007   8818  09:08 AM     00:13  I S-E  D 618        #45269021726        00:01
 8013   8811  09:09 AM     00:01  I S-E  D 770        #436217227         00:01
 8014         09:10 AM     00:16  I S-E  D 652        #4523859922        00:01
```

I'd like to insert it into an array with all parameters, even if empty,
but I can't get it work.

I tried this:

```
$fh = fopen('captures/131210.txt','r');
 while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
  $tempexp = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
  print_r($tempexp);
  echo "<br />";
 }
fclose($fh)
```

But it gives out weird outputs for some values, like this:

> Array ( [0] => [1] => " [2] => 8812 [3] => 00:16 [4] => )

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the layout of your text file is purely based on spaces you can used the exact columns to extract the data. Since the columns are not of equal width you cannot simply write it in one loop.

Use the [substr](https://www.php.net/substr) function to get part of the line (first number is index, second number is length to read)

```
$fh = fopen('captures/131210.txt','r');
 while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
  $co = substr($line, 0, 7);
  $user = substr($line, 7, 6);
  ... etc ...
  echo "<br />";
 }
fclose($fh)
```

You might need to parse the separate parts further down dependent on the content and what you want to do with it - parse as integer, date, time etc.